# How to overwrite CSS color scheme settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In HTML.
Now I know we can ask CSS to do something when user change their system color scheme, like

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
```

But what if I want to overwrite that setting like I need light color scheme at night, but I don’t want to change my system color scheme settings, is there any JavaScript or jQuery way to fool CSS (to proceed the dark park even when system is light, or opposite ), so I can switch webpage color scheme by click some element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first get the current time in 24 hour format like so:

`var dayNight = (new Date()).getHours();`

Now, you most probably have 2 classes with background color, 1 for day and 1 for night.

So, you can use `if/else` statement to decide when you want to add or remove a class using JQuery.

So in my example, when the `.dayNight` is bigger or equals to 7 (7am) and lesser than 19 (7pm), it adds the `.day` class and removes the .`night` class.

And when the `.dayNight` is bigger or equals to 0 (12 midnight) AND if it is smaller than 7 (7am), it adds the `.night` class and removes the `.day` class.

Also, when it is bigger or equals to 19 (7pm) and equals or lesser than 23 (11pm) it does the same above. We've already assigned 0 (12 midnight) in the above code, so we can set it to 23 (11pm) here.

Try this:

```js
var dayNight = (new Date()).getHours();

if(dayNight>=7 && dayNight < 19) {
  $( "#display" ).removeClass( "night" ).addClass( "day" );
}

if((dayNight>=0 && dayNight<7) || (dayNight>=19 && dayNight <=23)) {
 $( "#display" ).removeClass( "day" ).addClass( "night" );
}
```

```css
.day {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.night {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
Hello!
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, right now I've only set 2 rules to make it easy to understand. So I've set 12am to 12pm, but in reality , 8am is not considered night, so you might wanna change those timings to say 7am to 7pm considered day and 7pm to 7am considered night. Just change the value from 12 to 7.

Comment: Thank you but I want to keep the css prefer part and let it work and add JavaScript part to override the color scheme of whole HTML, is there a JavaScript way to simply like”set_color_scheme(‘light’);” something like that?

Comment: @Duke Yes, that `.day` is an example. To set your color scheme, choose the style you've set in your css. Find the class name for your day and night scheme and replace it with my `.day` and `.night`